# Why unset() doesn't work in PHP ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator, unset

So there is a problem with this, but i'm blind to it.
Even after reading the documentation twice ([PHP Comparison Operators](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php))

```
isset($items['blog']) ? unset($items['blog']) : NULL;
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_UNSET

Comment: The error says, that `T_UNSET` (that is the token for `unset`) is unexpected at that line. That means you can not place it there. That's all. Remove it and you're fine. This has not much to do with the ternary operator btw..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A @Bryan points out, no <strike>function</strike> calls to language constructs within the ternary operator. Since there's no return value involved at all here though, just do:

```
unset($items['blog']);
```

There's no need to check if the value is set or not beforehand. If it is not, `unset` simply won't do anything.

Comment: there is no problem with function calls in ternary operators. but unset is no function but a language construct. and that's why it does not work. However your suggestion is still the best suggestion  here code-wise, just not the right explanation.

Comment: @hakre I know you edited the other post but I can't @ you on it since you haven't commented there. Just so you're aware, `if` and `for` are not language constructs. The full list of constructs is the third category of reserved words on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: @PaulP.R.O.: I have a more relaxed view on language constructs here, and I think the example with `if` or `for` are better. Because: `isset` does work: http://codepad.org/MCSHpbTG

Comment: @hakre That is very interesting. I'm surpised that isset doesn't cause another error. Perhaps it's because it's a language construct that returns a boolean, in case you want to nest ternary isset tests.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O.: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php which explains the error message.

Comment: @hakre That doesn't explain why you can't use it in a ternary operator though, but can use isset. I just discovered this: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php which explains it. An expression is "anything which has a value". `unset` just like `echo` has no return value. So they cannot be used there since an expression is expected. Any function can be used there and some language constructs which return values can also be used.

Comment: Although die and exit can still be used oddly enough, even though they are not expressions.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O.: No, otherwise `die` won't work, but it does: http://codepad.org/wmd66UC8 - it's just a parser thing, PHP tells you syntax error, accept it. You can not argue with the information given in the manual, if you want to explain this technically, take a look into the PHP source-code and see where those parser errors are created. - Edit: Ah now I see you found die as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use unset inside of the ternary operation because it is not an expression that can be operated on. It's a language construct (like `isset` and `echo`) and can't be placed there.

Just use it and you're fine, no decision is needed:

```
unset($items['blog']);
```

Comment: An additional note, you actually don't even need the if statement. unset($items['blog']) won't return an error if the key doesn't exist, that's probably your best bet :)

Comment: This isn't true. You can run a function inside the ternary operator: http://codepad.org/X5bDeXwb

Comment: exactly, unset is not a function, it's an operator.

Answer (score 3):

The error says, that `T_UNSET` (that is the [token<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) for `unset`) is unexpected at that line. That means you can not place it there. That's all. Remove it and you're fine:

```
unset($items['blog']);
```

This has not much to do with the ternary operator btw., and as the code example shows, you don't need that operator for `unset` anyway.

If you love ternary operators very much, you can eval the unset:

```
isset($items['blog']) ? eval('unset($items[\'blog\'])') : NULL;
```

but that's not a serious suggestion because not very straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

just a suggest regarding to benchmark matters : only use ternary syntax when you have to e.g in a view or if you really need one line code; therefore if else operator is much faster

Comment: Interesting; have you tested this or just noticed the difference? This is also too bad, not that a ternary is easier to read than an if/else, but I love the convenience.